# No-JS mobile navigation with good accessibility

Tags: html, css, navigation, accessibility

Right now I am working on the website of a project working with handicapped people and looking for a mobile navigation with great accessibility and a no-js fallback. First i was thinking about using the :target-pseudoclass to open and close the navigation, but I cant open a sub-navigation this way since the main-nav closes if it looses the target. Then I was looking at the checkbox hack but there I get a roblem with the accessibility since Checkboxes or Radio-Buttons have another use case, a different way of control and also they are form elements, you should not use outside a form. Is there any clean and accessible way to get such a navigation working?

I hve a navigation like thw following:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="link.html">Link</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>
          <a href="link2.html"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The navigation can be quite big so I dont want the sub menus to be visible the whole time (if possible), so that you dont need to scroll such along time.
This is not a question to give me the exact code, I just need some hints to find a way for an easy accessible no-js mobile navigation with sub-menus (maybe with an example)

Comment: Can you please show what you were trying, so that we understand the problem?

Comment: Hum... Elementary question: The noscript tag won't work?

Comment: This is not about the technical aspects, noscript tags work and modernizr works as well, this is a question about usability and accessibility and a way to find a good concept for a navigation

Comment: Accessibility does not mean that you have to work without javascript. The important thing is that you add more informations to you html elements and that you use javascript the right way. A screen reader needs to know what your html elements are for and to improve navigation with keyword the browser needs to know how to deal with the elements. With aria attributes you can add those informations to html elements. For more informations:  [MDN: ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA)  and [ARIA Examples](http://heydonworks.com/practical_aria_examples)